# Correct usage of suspended hyphens in "upper- and lowercase"

Tags: hyphenation, suspended-hyphen

I have seen some people using them while others not. Should I still use a suspended hyphen in the following snippet?

> I have used upper- and lowercase in my script.

Comment: The question here differs from that at the claimed duplicate in that << I have used upper- and lowercase in my script. (?)>> suggests the **introduction** of a hyphen which is not present in the original elements (uppercase, lowercase).

Comment: [Probably closer, if badly phrased: 'How does one correctly use a suspended hyphen when the words aren't written together?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/556831/how-does-one-correctly-use-a-suspended-hyphen-when-the-words-arent-written-toge)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the suspended hyphen. Because they are compound words with identical second elements, the use of such a hyphen is acceptable.

Comment: Hello, Steph. This question has been marked as a duplicate, but if you look at the accepted answer there, you will see that it does not come across purely as opinion, but includes research and analysis in addition to not insisting that 'you should [always / in this case] use the suspended hyphen' (Fowler seems to go too far the other way).